# SQL round down by significance (equivalent of excel's floor function)

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssms

I need the something in SQL that mimics excel's FLOOR() function.  SQL's `FLOOR()` function only takes one argument and rounds down to nearest whole number.  But I need to be able to choose the significance, like in excel's `FLOOR()` function.

Example: in excel `FLOOR(6.03,.125) = 6.00`, and `FLOOR(6.63,.125) = 6.625`
But in SQL so far I've tried `ROUND(6.63,.125)` and that `= 7.00`
and `ROUND(6.63,.125,1) = 6.00`

Does anyone know how I can achieve what I'm going for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @V float = 6.3
Declare @F float = 0.125

Select Floor(@V)+floor((@V-Floor(@V))/@F)*@F
```

Returns

```
6.25
```

> **EDIT - If a UDF is desired**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Stat-Round-To](@Value float,@Round float)
Returns Float
As
Begin

Return case when @Round=0 then NULL else Floor(@Value)+Floor((@Value-Floor(@Value))/@Round)*@Round end

End
-- Syntax Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Round-To](10.13,.125) -- 10.125
```

Comment: I'll give you a vote if you get rid of the `IIF`... I still have nightmares from my time with Access. Fair trade?

Comment: @SqlZim Done.  Personally, I'm Indifferent to IIF() and/or case.  They render the same  :)

Comment: Looks good! Only other question is if performance wouldn't  be better with an inline TVF instead of a scalar. Still a good solution though. +1

Comment: @SqlZim Can't imagine how a TVF would make it more performant

Comment: @SqlZim SQLZim created a proof-of-performance of Scalar vs. Table-Value function,  The results are most impressive http://rextester.com/JHKJZS29068